# Python dictionary will be sent to c# dll, dynamic vs. static types issue

Tags: c#, python, ironpython

I need to run a python code, this code will generate a nested dictionary {"str","list"}, the list inside had many types like int or bool

I need to use this dictionary inside a c# code, I need this dictionary exactly the same as it was in python.

I did this

```
        try:
            #create a dictionary of all tests stats
            resultStat = ResDesc.__dict__

            #convert this dictionary from python type to c# generic type so 
            SQSManagedUI.dll can handle the information contained inside

            resultStatDict = Dictionary[String,String]()

            #unify the key value pairs to be all strings, even the Boolean 
            values will be converted #to 'Str', so DLLs will be able to 
            process it. 

            for k,v in resultStat.items():
                if isinstance(v,str):
                    resultStatDict[k]=v
                else:
                    v= str(v)
                    resultStatDict[k]=v

        #send the dictionary to SQSmanagedUI dll for proces sing as 
        Dict[string:string]

        resultWindow=SQSManagedUI.Dialogs.ShowResultManager(resultStatDict)
    except:
        traceback.print_exc()
```

but this gives me a dictionary with string/string pairs, What can I do to preserve my types inside the list (bool, str, int).

I know a little bit about reflections in c#, I use Iron Python in my python code.

Can any one help please, thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you post an example of how your dict looks like?

Comment: I'm not sure about how C#/IronPython interop but C# supports [dynamic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/dynamic). One of it's usages is to support languages like python (it is even mentioned on the page).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To operate with python you can utilize C#'s support for [dynamic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/dynamic) type.

> The dynamic type simplifies access to COM APIs such as the Office Automation APIs, and also to dynamic APIs such as IronPython libraries, and to the HTML Document Object Model (DOM).

Comment: @Ahmed you're welcome, sorry that my answer is really short but I've never used `dynamic` to interop with python myself.